# Issue with deploying Java 11 app to Heroku from GitLab

Tags: java, maven, heroku, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to deploy my app to Heroku from GitLab. I have a Java 11 Spring Boot project and am using maven. The app successfully builds and runs in GitLab, but fails in the deploy stage with the following error:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project XYZ: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

maven-build:
  image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11
  stage: build
  script: "mvn package -B"

maven-test:
  image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11
  stage: test
  script: "mvn test -B"

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: ruby:latest
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
    - gem install dpl
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_APP_PRODUCTION --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
  only:
    - master
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Your java version is too old

Comment: Yes, I know. How do I change it for the deploy stage?

Comment: Install it?  You already run apt-get.

Comment: Correction: it was in fact Heroku that was defaulting to java 8. Adding a system.properties file and setting the java version to 11 seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I suppose your stages `build` and `test` are running one after another? If so you are running several parts in duplicate cause the lifecycle `package` contains `test` and several other steps.. see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html